# What is the p-th moment finite in the definition of Wasserstein space?

Tags: probability, analysis, wasserstein

I am confused about the following notation:
[image]

For a simple case, let $X=R^d$ or $X=R$. What dose
$$
\int_X \|x\|^pd\mu(x)
$$
mean for a Borel probability measure $\mu$?

For $X=R$, then $x\in R$ is a 1-dimensional case. If we take $\|\cdot\|$ is the Euclidean metric. So
$$
\int_X \|x\|^pd\mu(x)=\int_R \|x\|_2^pd\mu(x)=\int_R|x|^pd\mu(x)=E_{X\sim \mu} [|X|^p]
$$

However, I am confused about $X=R^d$. It seems that it will be for $x=(x_1,\dots,x_d)$,
$$
\int_X \|x\|_2^pd\mu(x)=\int_{R^d} (\sqrt{x_1^2+\dots+x_d^2})^pd\mu(x)
$$
Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\mathcal X=\mathbb R^d$, you can choose the Euclidean norm or the $\ell^p$ norm, which is equivalent, that is, there exists constants $C_{p,d}$ and $C'_{p,d}$ such that $C_{p,d}\left(\sum_{k=1}^d\lvert x_k\rvert^p\right)^{1/p}\leqslant \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^dx_k^2}\leqslant C'_{p,d}\left(\sum_{k=1}^d\lvert x_k\rvert^p\right)^{1/p}$. With this in mind, we derive that
$$
\mathcal W\left(\mathbb R^d\right)=\left\{\mu\in\mathbb P\left(\mathbb R^d\right), \int_{\mathbb R}\lvert x\rvert^p d\mu_i(x)<\infty\mbox{ for each }1\leqslant i\leqslant d\right\}
$$
where $\mu_i$ is the $i$-marginal: $\mu_i(B)=\mu\left(\mathbb R^{i-1}\times B\times \mathbb R^{d-i}\right)$.

You characterisation is also correct by the way.

Comment: Thanks! Is your $\mu\in P(R^d)$ the Borel probability measures on $R^d$?

Comment: It is a Borel probability measure indeed.